# Kotlin generics constraint

Tags: generics, kotlin

I want to make a class that can accept limited generic type, so that my class can only accept the subclass of some particular class. But without so many cast. My code looks like this:

```
open class SomeClass<V> where V : SomeType { 
  private val vc: PS<SomeType> = PS.create()
  protected val z: ZQ<V> = vc.doSmt(-1).map { it as V }

  open fun onVc(v: V) {
    vc.on(v)
  } 
}
```

With that code, warning appeared to use `in` variance to the generic type. Changing to `SomeClass<in V>`. But when I call `onVc(v)` where v is a subtype of `SomeType`, it is rejected. `v` is type `Nothing`. I read the kotlin generic documentation here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html but still confused.

---

Edit:

I will still put the original code there and add a better and representative code here.

```
open class SomeClass<V> (params: IgnoreThis) where V: SomeType {
  private val vc: PublishSubject<SomeType> = PublishSubject.create()
  protected val z: Observable<V> =
    vc.filter { it !is SubClassOfSomeType }.map { it as V }

  open fun onVc(v: V) {
    vc.onNext(v)
  }
}
```

And this is `SomeType`, its super and sub class looks like

```
interface SuperSomeType<S> {
  fun x(): Observable<S>
}

interface SomeType : SuperSomeType<EnumType1>
interface SomeOtherType : SuperSomeType<EnumType2> // just to show why I used SuperSomeType interface

class SubClassOfSomeType : SomeType {
  override fun x(): Observable<EnumType1> {
    return Observable.empty()
  }
}
```

Thanks for the suggestion for make it clearer

Comment: Can you please make a minimal, __complete and verifiable__ example? There's a lot of undefined classes and functions in your code. It makes it hard for me to try it out.

Comment: You can most likely just define your class as `open class SomeClass<V : SomeType>` though.

Comment: @marstran okay I will add the complete version tomorrow. Yeah that's shorter but `where` is used in case I want to upperbound more than 1 type. Thanks the suggestion btw.

Comment: You can have multiple upper bounds by using the `where` keyword: `open class SomeClass<V> where V : Sometype, V: SomeOtherType, V: SomeThirdType`

Comment: The example is still incomplete. The Rx classes are still undefined. The question asks about a call to `SomeClass<V>::onVc`, but there's none in the question.